# T-SQL statement won't accept a variable as role name in a grant statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, variables, roles, sql-grant

I want to create a stored proc in SQL Server 2008 to create database roles and grant permissions to them, that takes one parameter, an `nvarchar` that represents a role name that is to be created, but im not sure how to write this.

I am able to create the role with this

```
EXEC sp_addrole @RoleName
```

but when I try to grant permissions to the role with this

```
Grant select on dbo.someTable to  @RoleName
```

it won't accept the @RoleName, how do I go about doing this?

thanks

Comment: A lot of those "management" statements do **not** accept variables - use explicit names, or then you must use dynamic SQL (build your explicit SQL statement as a string variable, and then execute it) to achieve your goal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL to generate the sql statement as text, which can then be run using EXEC

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'Grant select on dbo.someTable to ' + @RoleName  -- protect if required
EXEC (sql)
```